Call Adf Pipeline with params C#
I am getting an error message when trying to run the following code in asp.net core application. Here is the code.
var armClient = new ArmClient(credential, subscriptionId);

var subscription = armClient.GetSubscriptionResource(new ResourceIdentifier($"/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}"));

try
{
    await foreach (var resourceGroupDilo in subscription.GetResourceGroups().GetAllAsync())
    {
        if(resourceGroupDilo.Data.Name == "xxxx_group")
        {
            var dataFactory = await resourceGroupDilo.GetDataFactoryAsync(factoryName);
            var pipelineRun = await dataFactory.Value.GetDataFactoryPipelines().GetAsync(pipelineName);

            var parameters = new Dictionary<string, BinaryData>
            {
                { "test", BinaryData.FromString("value1") },
                { "test2", BinaryData.FromString("value2") }
            };

            var pipelineRunResponse = await pipelineRun.Value.CreateRunAsync(parameters);

            return pipelineRunResponse.Value.RunId.ToString();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
}

Now it gets all the correct resources and if I call the adf pipeline without parameters it works. This is the error I get
{"'v' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."}

This is what the pipeline looks like



{"'v' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."}

Here, the issue is you are using FromString() while passing parameters.
As per the documentation, you need to use FromObjectAsJson('<parameter_value>') .
I have followed the same documentation, and this is the complete code that worked for me.

using Azure;
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Core.Expressions.DataFactory;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.DataFactory;
using Azure.ResourceManager.DataFactory.Models;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


string tenantID = "<tenantID>";
string applicationId = "<APP_ID>";
string secret1 = "<secret_value>";
string subscriptionId = "sub_ID";
string factoryName = "<ADF_name>";
string pipelineName = "<pipeline_name>";

ArmClient armClient = new ArmClient(
    new ClientSecretCredential(tenantID, applicationId, secret1, new TokenCredentialOptions
    {
        AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
    }),
    subscriptionId,
    new ArmClientOptions { Environment = ArmEnvironment.AzurePublicCloud }
);

var subscription = armClient.GetSubscriptionResource(new ResourceIdentifier($"/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}"));

await foreach (var resourceGroupDilo in subscription.GetResourceGroups().GetAllAsync())
{
    if (resourceGroupDilo.Data.Name == "<RG_name>")
    {
        var dataFactory = await resourceGroupDilo.GetDataFactoryAsync(factoryName);
        var pipelineRun = await dataFactory.Value.GetDataFactoryPipelines().GetAsync(pipelineName);

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, BinaryData>
            {
                { "test", BinaryData.FromObjectAsJson("Govindula ")},
                { "test2", BinaryData.FromObjectAsJson("Rakesh")}
            };

        var pipelineRunResponse = await pipelineRun.Value.CreateRunAsync(parameters);
        Console.WriteLine("The pipeline run id :"+ pipelineRunResponse.Value.RunId);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Done");

I have created parameters test and test2 in the ADF pipeline and executed the above code.
Code output:

Triggered pipeline run id and parameter values:

